# map infoWindow doesn't displayed from the first click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-redux

I've checked around and read a couple articles on this issue and tried a few things but nothing seems to be working. The issue is when the marker is clicked the first time nothing happens. The second time its clicked then the event is fired off.The infowindow doesn't shows before 4 or 5 clicks, I don't know what i have done wrong.
This is not acutally brower issue. Because, I have checked with all browers.
I am using below code to open up a infowindow in my map:

```
 import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import _ from 'lodash';
import {
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow,
  TrafficLayer,
} from 'react-google-maps';
import {loadGodViewDrivers} from '../../../actions/driverActions';
import {loadGodViewBranches} from '../../../actions/branchActions';
import './OverviewMap.scss';

const actions = {
  loadGodViewDrivers,
  loadGodViewBranches,
};

const GoogleMapsContainer = withGoogleMap(props => {
  function getPosition(marker) {
    return {
      lat: marker.address
          ? marker.address.location.latitude
          : marker.location.latitude,
      lng: marker.address
          ? marker.address.location.longitude
          : marker.location.longitude,
    };
  }

  return (

      <GoogleMap
          ref={props.onMapLoad}
          defaultZoom={11}
          options={props.mapsOptions}
          onDragEnd={props.mapChanged}
          onZoomChanged={props.mapChanged}
          defaultCenter={props.mapCenter}
      >
        <TrafficLayer autoUpdate/>
        {typeof props.mapHolderRef !== 'undefined' &&
        _.size(props.branches) > 0 && (
            props.branches.map((it, i) => {
                  return (
                      <Marker
                          key={i}
                          position={getPosition(it)}                       
                          onClick={() => props.onMarkerClick(it)}
                          icon={'/img/merchant.png'}
                      >

                        {it.showInfo && (
                            <InfoWindow
                                onCloseClick={() => props.onMarkerClose(it)}>
                              {it.merchant ? (<div
                                  style={ {display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                <div className="pull-left text-center"><img
                                    src={it.merchant.logo}
                                    className="img-circle" alt="Restaurant logo"
                                    width="90" height="90"/>
                                  <div style={ {height: '12px'} }></div>
                                  <div style={ {height: '20x'}}><span
                                      className={ it.merchant.suspended
                                          ? 'label label-danger'
                                          : 'label label-success'}>{ it.merchant.suspended
                                      ? 'suspended'
                                      : 'active'}</span>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="pull-right"
                                     style={ {
                                       paddingLeft: '15px',
                                       display: 'flex',
                                       flexDirection: 'column',
                                       alignItems: 'center',
                                     }}>
                                  <h4 className="text-center"
                                      style={{paddingBottom: '8px'}}>{it.name}<br/>
                                    <small>{it.address.firstLine}</small>
                                  </h4>
                                  <div><p style={{fontSize: '14px'}}>
                                    <span style={{
                                      backgroundColor: '#337ab7',
                                      border: '2px solid #2e6da4',
                                      fontSize: '15px',
                                      color: '#fff',
                                      display: 'inline-flex',
                                      alignItems: 'center',
                                      justifyContent: 'center',
                                      borderRadius: '50%',
                                      width: '32px',
                                      height: '32px',
                                      marginRight: '6px',
                                    }}><i
                                        className="fa fa-cutlery"></i></span><a
                                      href={`/merchants/${it.merchant._id}`}>{it.merchant.name}</a>
                                  </p><p style={{
                                    fontSize: '14px',
                                    marginBottom: '0',
                                  } }>
                                    <span
                                        style={{
                                          backgroundColor: '#337ab7',
                                          border: '2px solid #2e6da4',
                                          fontSize: '15px',
                                          color: '#fff',
                                          display: 'inline-flex',
                                          alignItems: 'center',
                                          justifyContent: 'center',
                                          borderRadius: '50%',
                                          width: '32px',
                                          height: '32px',
                                          marginRight: '6px',
                                        }}><i
                                        className="fa fa-phone"></i></span><a
                                      href={`tel:${it.phone}`}>{it.phone}</a></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>) : <div className="text-center">No merchant
                                data</div>}
                            </InfoWindow>)}
                      </Marker>
                  );

                },
            )
        )}
        {typeof props.mapHolderRef !== 'undefined' &&
        _.size(props.drivers) > 0 && (
            props.drivers).map((it, i) => {
              if(it.available || (it.orderStatus && it.currentOrder && it.orderStatus !== null && it.currentOrder !== null))
              return (
                  <Marker
                      key={i * 2}
                      position={getPosition(it)}
                      onClick={() => props.onMarkerClick(it)}
                      onCloseClick={() => props.onMarkerClose(it)}
                      icon={it.orderStatus === 'en_route' ? '/img/driver_green.png' : it.orderStatus === 'waiting_pack' ? '/img/driver_yellow.png' : it.available ? '/img/driver_grey.png' : '/img/driver_red.png'}
                  >

                    {it.showInfo && (
                        <InfoWindow
                            onCloseClick={() => props.onMarkerClose(it)}>
                          <div style={ {display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                            <div className="pull-left text-center"><img
                                src={it.userPhoto}
                                className="img-circle" alt="User photo"
                                width="90" height="90"/>
                              <div style={ {height: '12px'} }></div>
                              <div style={ {height: '20x'}}><span
                                  className={ !it.available
                                      ? 'label label-danger'
                                      : 'label label-success'}>{ !it.available
                                  ? 'unavailable'
                                  : 'available'}</span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="pull-right"
                                 style={ {
                                   paddingLeft: '15px',
                                   display: 'flex',
                                   flexDirection: 'column',
                                   alignItems: 'center',
                                 }}>
                              <h4 className="text-center"
                                  style={{paddingBottom: '8px'}}><a
                                  href={`/drivers/${it._id}`}>{it.userName}</a>
                                <br/>
                                <small>{it.userEmail}</small>
                              </h4>
                              <div><p style={{fontSize: '14px'}}>
                                    <span style={{
                                      backgroundColor: '#337ab7',
                                      border: '2px solid #2e6da4',
                                      fontSize: '15px',
                                      color: '#fff',
                                      display: 'inline-flex',
                                      alignItems: 'center',
                                      justifyContent: 'center',
                                      borderRadius: '50%',
                                      width: '32px',
                                      height: '32px',
                                      marginRight: '6px',
                                    }}><i
                                        className="fa fa-cutlery"></i></span>
                                <a href={`/orders/${it.currentOrder}/`}>Current order</a>
                              </p><p style={{
                                fontSize: '14px',
                                marginBottom: '0',
                              } }>
                                    <span
                                        style={{
                                          backgroundColor: '#337ab7',
                                          border: '2px solid #2e6da4',
                                          fontSize: '15px',
                                          color: '#fff',
                                          display: 'inline-flex',
                                          alignItems: 'center',
                                          justifyContent: 'center',
                                          borderRadius: '50%',
                                          width: '32px',
                                          height: '32px',
                                          marginRight: '6px',
                                        }}><i
                                        className="fa fa-phone"></i></span><a
                                  href={`tel:${it.workPhone}`}>{it.workPhone}</a>
                              </p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </InfoWindow>)}
                  </Marker>
              );
            },
        )}

      </GoogleMap>
  );
});
class OverviewMap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      center: null,
    };

    this.handleRecenterClick = this.handleRecenterClick.bind(this);
    this.handleMapsRef = this.handleMapsRef.bind(this);
    this.mapChanged = _.debounce(this.mapChanged.bind(this), 500);

  }

  handleMapLoad = this.handleMapLoad.bind(this);

  handleMapLoad(map) {
    this._mapComponent = map;
    this.mapHolderRef = map;

    this.mapChanged();
  }

  mapChanged() {
    const bounds = this.mapHolderRef.getBounds();

    const ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
    const sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
    this.props.loadGodViewDrivers({
      nw: {lat: ne.lat(), lng: sw.lng()},
      se: {lat: sw.lat(), lng: ne.lng()},
    });

    this.props.loadGodViewBranches({
      nw: {lat: ne.lat(), lng: sw.lng()},
      se: {lat: sw.lat(), lng: ne.lng()},
    });

    this.setState({
      center: {
        lat: this.mapHolderRef.getCenter().lat(),
        lng: this.mapHolderRef.getCenter().lng(),
      },
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.mapChanged();
    this.mapChangedInterval = setInterval(this.mapChanged, 2000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.mapChangedInterval);
  }

  getDefaultCenter() {
    return {
      lat: 29.234232862891145,
      lng: 47.947988063964885,
    };
  }

  handleRecenterClick() {
    const center = this.getDefaultCenter();

    this.setState({
      center: {
        lat: center.lat + Math.pow(10, -5),
        lng: center.lng,
      },
    });
  }

  handleMapsRef(mapHolder) {
    this.mapHolderRef = mapHolder;
    this.googleMaps = mapHolder && mapHolder.props.map;

    if (this.googleMaps) this.mapChanged();
  }

  handleMarkerClick = this.handleMarkerClick.bind(this);
  handleMarkerClose = this.handleMarkerClose.bind(this);

  handleMarkerClick(targetMarker) {
    this.setState({ 
       branches: this.props.branches.map(marker => {
        if (marker == targetMarker) {
          return {
            ...marker,
            showInfo: true,
          };
        }
        return marker;

      }),
      drivers: this.props.drivers.map(marker => {
        if (marker == targetMarker) {
          return {
            ...marker,
            showInfo: true,
          };
        }
        return marker;
      }),
    });
  }

  handleMarkerClose(targetMarker) {
    this.setState({
      branches: this.props.branches.map(marker => {
        if (marker == targetMarker) {
          return {
            ...marker,
            showInfo: true,
          };
        }
        return marker;
      }),
      drivers: this.props.drivers.map(marker => {
        if (marker == targetMarker) {
          return {
            ...marker,
            showInfo: false,
          };
        }
        return marker;
      }),

    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.branches !== nextProps.branches ||
        _.size(this.state.branches) === 0) {
      this.setState({
        branches: _.map(nextProps.branches, (marker, i) => {
          return {
            ...marker,
            showInfo: typeof this.state.branches !== 'undefined'
                ? typeof this.state.branches[i] !== 'undefined'
                    ? this.state.branches[i].showInfo
                    : false
                : false,
          };
        }),
      });
    }
    if (this.props.drivers !== nextProps.drivers ||
        _.size(this.state.drivers) === 0) {
      this.setState({
        drivers: _.map(nextProps.drivers, (marker, i) => {
            return {
              ...marker,
              showInfo: typeof this.state.drivers !== 'undefined'
                  ? typeof this.state.drivers[i] !== 'undefined'
                      ? this.state.drivers[i].showInfo
                      : false
                  : false,
            };
        }),
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const mapCenter = this.state.center || this.getDefaultCenter();
    const mapsOptions = {
      streetViewControl: true,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      signInControl: true,
    };

    return (
        <GoogleMapsContainer
            containerElement={
              <div style={{height: '100%'}}/>
            }
            mapElement={
              <div style={{height: '100%'}}/>
            }
            onMapLoad={this.handleMapLoad}
            mapCenter={mapCenter}
            mapsOptions={mapsOptions}
            mapChanged={this.mapChanged}
            mapHolderRef={this.mapHolderRef}
            mapRef={this.handleMapsRef}
            branches={this.state.branches}
            drivers={this.state.drivers}
            onMarkerClick={this.handleMarkerClick}
            onMarkerClose={this.handleMarkerClose}
        />
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {


  return {
    branches: state.branches.godView,
    drivers: state.drivers.godView,
  };

}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(OverviewMap);
```

The above code, calling while loading on the marker in the google map. At fist time, first click on the marker through ajax call, the content of the infowindow comes as response. In the second click the infowindow will open. Next time onwards, clicking on the marker loading the infowindow comes in first click. 
Has any one had this bug before ? could some one help me to sort this issue please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one else is bothering to answer my question, i found it by my self,:
my mistake that i was comparing two Javascript objects "marker == targetMarker".
So for that  just updated this line to marker == targetMarker._id" and it works well. Hope it will be helpful for many of you who are stucked for something like this. If you want to compare two Javascripts objects you need to use a specific attribute like i just do with the id.